# Can't run function from button onClick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a function from a button onClick event and for some really strange reason, it doesn't want to work.

I want to get the function to run from the button with the onClick attribute of "all()" however it doesn't work but when I changed it to an anchor with a href attribute of "javascript:all()" it worked?

**Html:**

```
<div id="content">
    <input id="heroes" type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield-typeahead" />
    <button id="all" onClick="all()">Select/Deselect All</button>
    <button id="random" onClick="random()">Random</button>

    <!-- Example Link to Prove Point -->
    <a href="javascript:all()">Example: Select/Deselect All</a>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/2T9TA/

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? If need be, I'll make a javascript click event instead but I'd rather not.

Comment: Why not add the events with jQuery since you're using it?

Comment: @elclanrs Just because jQuery is on the page doesn't mean it needs to be used. Sometimes there are simpler ways to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why its not working, but I tried changing you all name function to allt and it worked:

```
<a onclick="allt()">Example: Select/Deselect All</a>
function allt() {
//your code
}
```

Comment: Haha yeah me too, as far as I know all is not a reserved word

Comment: @Phil Thanks. I'm surprised this doesn't work in the browsers that don't support this still. But to no surprise, of course it was Microsoft causing this as they always do.

Comment: @Spedwards: `document.all` is an existing property in most browsers, Chrome and Firefox as well. And the properties of `document` are imported into the scope of inline event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a type attribute in your  tag. So, try this:

```
<button id="all" type="button" onClick="all()">Select/Deselect All</button>
```

Comment: It's not that. When you don't set a type to a button, it defaults to button.

Comment: `button`s are *submit* button by default. And if they are not inside a form, there is no difference between "submit" buttons and "button" buttons.